# Serve SPA before running tests on cypress js

Tags: npm, circleci, cypress

With Cypress I can test my dev subdomain easily. I have an angular/react application where when I make a `dist` (including `index.html`), I want to run Cypress tests against the built files.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to serve a `dist` folder, (like `serve` package of `npm`) before starting Cypress tests.

I know that I can serve the `index.html` on another terminal tab, but this is not going to happen on CircleCi (my CI).

Is there anyway that Cypress can replace the localhost and serve static files before starting the actual tests?

Answer (score 2):

I used `browser-sync` to launch a server that distribute my static files.

You need to install 3 packages: `cypress` (obviously), `browser-sync` to launch a server, and `npm-run-all` to launch a server and cypress consecutively.

```
npm install --save-dev cypress
npm install --save-dev browser-sync
npm install --save-dev npm-run-all
```

Here is an example of the npm scripts configuration that you will need to add in your `package.json`. Don't forget to customize the `<port>` (ex: 4000) and `<folder>` that contains the path to your SPA (ex: public).

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "cypress": "cypress run",
    "server": "browser-sync start --port <port> --server <folder> --no-open",
    "test": "run-p -r server cypress"
  }
}
```

Now you have to write your first `Hello world` test:

```
describe('My App', function() {
    it('is up', function() {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:4000');

        cy.contains('Hello world!');
    });
});
```

That's it! We can launch our test:

```
npm test
```

Comment: Perhaps look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server which is a bit more lightweight and more suited for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:

I installed

```
npm i serve
```

and added

```
serve: "serve -s <build-folder>"
```

to my `package.json`. And then in your e.g. travis.yml you add

```
- npm run serve & 
- npm test
```

The `&` at the end of your command will make it run in the backend and thus the test can run right after it. Since `serve` is pretty fast serving the static files there is no need for the `npm test` to wait either AND you do not have to worry about stopping the `npm run serve` afterwards since most CI environments are cleaning up background processes automatically after your tests finished.

Most of the information above can also be found [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#).

Comment: would this cause issue if same port is running on 2 jenkins pr for same repo at the same time i.e 2 separate PRs?